# Problem facing when I define a new operator

Tags: macros, math-operators

Working with `LaTeX`, I want to define a new operator, specifically a projection operator. I am able to define the operator, but it is not working how I want.

This is how I define the operator:

```latex
\newcommand{\proj}[1]{\text{proj}~(#1)}
```

but I want to define the operator like that: Whenever I give two inputs (u,v) to it, it gives me back with proj_u(v) like, that but I am unable to do it.

The final result should look like this:
[image: It should look like this]

[image]

This is my code and result:

Comment: And now you know that is not what `\text` is for. It does not switch to upright, it switches to the current text font! Use `\DeclareMathOperator\proj{proj} `

Comment: Note that is is often not a good idea to include () in the macro as they cannot be scaled. Mathtools have methods for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want mainly proj<sub>**u**</sub>(**v**) and you don't need anything really complicated: after

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{proj}
```

in the preamble, you can type

```
\proj_{\mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{v})
```

in the document. However, if you want something fancier,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\projop}{proj}

\NewDocumentCommand{\proj}{mm}{%
  \projop_{#1}(#2)%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\cproj}{mm}{%
   \frac{\langle #2,#1\rangle}{\langle #1,#1\rangle}%
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\vec}{m}{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

This is the inline usage $\proj{\vec{u}}{\vec{v}}$, but the definition
can be seen as follows
\[
\proj{\vec{u}}{\vec{v}}=\cproj{\vec{u}}{\vec{v}}
\]

\end{document}
```

I recommend using proper naming for the vectors, so you can make their realization independent on input. If you want something else instead of `\mathbf`, just change the definition.

[image]

Comment: got it sir thank you

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{ \proj }{ s s m m }
  { \IfBooleanTF{ #1 }
                { \IfBooleanTF{ #2 }
                    { \frac{\langle #3,#4\rangle}{\|#3\|^2} #3 }
                    { \frac{\langle #3,#4\rangle}{\langle #3,#3\rangle} #3 } }
                { \operatorname{proj}\c_math_subscript_token{#3} #4 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\[\proj{u}{v} = \proj*{u}{v} = \proj**{u}{v}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The angular brackets should probably be made scalable.

Comment: Yeah, but it is straightforward@Gaussler

Comment: When we’re answering questions on this level, no, it’s not to be considered straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

We can define the `\proj` macro without expl3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\proj{\futurelet\next\projA}
\def\projA{\ifx\next*\expandafter\projB\else \expandafter\projD\fi}
\def\projB*{\futurelet\next\projC}
\def\projC{\ifx\next*\expandafter\projF\else \expandafter\projE\fi}
\def\projD#1#2{{\rm proj}_{#1}#2}
\def\projE#1#2{{\langle#1,#2\rangle\over\langle#1,#1\rangle}#1}
\def\projF*#1#2{{\langle#1,#2\rangle\over\|#1\|^2}#1}
\expandafter\let\expandafter\over\csname @@over\endcsname % to suppress amsmath obscure warning

\begin{document}

$$
   \proj{u}{v} = \proj*{u}{v} = \proj**{u}{v}
$$

\end{document}
```